# Python Versions under port

Tags: python, macos, version, port

Here's something I can't figure out.  Below is the capture of a terminal session. You will notice that the path to python is clear but the version is not consistent. The Python script is located at /opt/local/bin and that path is before /usr/bin in my path.  'which python' gives the correct path but only if I type the complete path do I get version 3.5.

Does anyone have an idea how this could happen? I would have thought that running `which python` would give the same results as just 'python'. The 2.7.6 version of Python is from /usr/bin/python.

```
michaels-imac:~ michaeltoth$ echo $PATH
/Users/michaeltoth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/Users/michaeltoth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/bin:/Users/michaeltoth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/michaeltoth/.rvm/bin

michaels-imac:~ michaeltoth$ which python

/opt/local/bin/python

michaels-imac:~ michaeltoth$ python --version

Python 2.7.6

michaels-imac:~ michaeltoth$ `which python` --version

Python 3.5.0a3

michaels-imac:~ michaeltoth$ /opt/local/bin/python --version

Python 3.5.0a3
```

Comment: Mac OS X comes with Python 2.7, and homebrew lets you install other Python versions, which end up in `/opt/local/bin`. This is all pretty bog-standard and normal. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Was this right after installing Python 3? `which` (an external program, not part of the shell) always uses the value of `PATH` to determine where the executable is, but your shell uses an internal hash table which may not have been updated since Python 3 was installed. Do you see the same issue after running  `hash python` or in a new shell?

Comment: What does `python -c "import sys;print sys.executable"` produce?

Comment: I get /opt/local/bin/python from that command. The problem I'm dealing with is just understanding why when I set the port select to python 3, it still starts with 2.7 but the paths all seem correct.

Comment: The problem is that python and \`which python\` don't give the same version when executed.